# How to use/integrate Apache OpenNLP in a (web) php application?

Tags: java, php, opennlp, named-entity-recognition

I am building a web application in php and I want to use natural language processing tools. I found the OpenNLP library but it is all java and I really have no experience with java.

I would like to use OpenNLP as a web service where I can deliver text and recieve the founded named-entities. 
Do I need to learn java or is their something out that I can use?
I can't find it and I am looking for hours now.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

You can use [PHP NLP Tools](http://php-nlp-tools.com/). It is a library for natural language processing written in php. Its development is driven by your needs for text classification, clustering, tokenizing, stemming etc.